# Getting result from two tables with a common key

Tags: sql, join

[image]

So I have two tables with a common key fk_exid which is a foreign key from some other table. Please help me to write a query to get the result shown in the image.

I tried:

```
SELECT
    payers.mid as payer_id,
    payers.name as payer_name,
    payers.amount as payer_amount,
    payees.mid as payee_id,
    payees.name as payee_name
FROM
    payers
LEFT OUTER JOIN payees ON payees.fk_exid = payers.fk_exid
WHERE
    payers.fk_exid = 1
```

But it has repeated values. I don't want a complete JOIN

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What about  joining the two tables  on `fk_exid`?

Comment: Ddi you actually do any research or try anything yourself?  This is a pretty basic task and there should be loads of existing examples out there.

Comment: I tried this .. 

SELECT payers.mid as `payer_id`, payers.name as `payer_name`, payers.amount as `payer_amount`, payees.mid as `payee_id`, payees.name as `payee_name`
FROM payers
LEFT OUTER JOIN payees ON payees.fk_exid = payers.fk_exid
WHERE payers.fk_exid = 1

but it has repeated values

I don't want a complete JOIN

Comment: What actually defines how the two tables are related? It looks like you're just trying to match them up "in order", but tables don't actually have an order - they are just a collection of data rows with **no** assumed order.

Comment: There is no relation between them. I just want to merge them in my result for particular fk_exid with null values for the table with lesser number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be optional one to one relationship and the result is the left join from payers to payees

please try the following

select * from payers p1 left outer join payees p2
on p1.fk_exid=p2.fk_exid

Comment: This will give me 4 x 3 tuples with repeating payees

Comment: no 4*3 will happen if you use full join , but with left join it will get all the results from the left table and the matching in the right and if no data in the right it will get nulls , this is the result you expect , so please give it a try :D

Comment: QUERY : SELECT payers.fk_exid, payers.mid as `payer_id`, payers.name as `payer_name`, payees.mid as `payee_id`, payees.name as `payee_name` 
FROM payers
LEFT OUTER JOIN payees ON payees.fk_exid = payers.fk_exid
WHERE payers.fk_exid = 6

RESULT : http://www.hostpic.org/images/1603031920130097.png

Comment: sorry I misunderstood it, you must have some thing to relate the rows which is vague and not clear in this case